# Retornar resultado de um select que está dentro de um loop

Tags: sql, plpgsql

Estou tentando a algumas horas pegar o resultado de um select que está dentro de uma função em pgsql. Não tenho muita experiência com sql. Pesquisei um pouco mas não obtive muito sucesso. Segue minha função para análise:

```
    create or replace function fimExpediente() returns varchar as $$
    declare 
        liga_antes record;
        new_select record;
        resultado varchar;
    begin
        for liga_antes in select bicolaborador, max(bidataevento) bidataevento
            from 
                tbbilhetes
            where 
                bicolaborador > 0 
            and 
                bidataevento > '12/01/2017' 
            and 
                bidataevento < '13/01/2017' 
            and 
                biignicao = 1 
            group by 
                bicolaborador
            loop
               select 
                   bidataevento 
               from tbbilhetes 
               where 
                   bidataevento >= liga_antes.bidataevento 
               and 
                   biignicao = 0 and bicolaborador = liga_antes.bicolaborador 
               order by 
                   bidataevento asc limit 1 
               into resultado;
         end loop;
         return resultado;

    end;
    $$ language 'plpgsql';

    select fimExpediente()
```

Esse `into` no final do select retorna somente o último resultado por estar dentro de um laço, porém preciso que retorne todos os valores do select. Tentei colocar `resultado:=` antes do select mas ai retorna erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Você quer retornar vários resultados ou quer que ele concatene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dê uma olhada no comando RETURN NEXT:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Você pode chamar ele de dentro do loop mesmo, pois ele só adiciona a linha a saída.

Edit: você vai ter que mudar o tipo de retorno da function para SETOF VARCHAR.